# Calculating complex integral.(Finding the principal Value)

Tags: contour-integration

The question is 
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} \, dx$$

My approach was as follows.
I converted the integral into a a complex integral.$\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos z}{z^2} \, dx$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2(z/2)}{z^2} \, dz$$

$$\implies \int_0^\infty \frac{\exp(iz)}{z^2}\,dz $$

And found out the residue of the function $\frac{\exp(iz)}{z^2}$ at $z = 0$.
It comes out to be $\operatorname{res}(f(z),0) = i$

Hence Answer = $\pi i \operatorname{res}(f(z),0) $

As i have to take the imaginary part I get the final answer as 0.

Am i right in doing this ?

Matlab suggests the answer to be $\pi /2$

Comment: Hint: use better the function $$f(x)=\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2}$$

Comment: Yes, I get the answer from that.But Can you hint me why this does not work.

Comment: There is no need to consider a principal value since $\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}$ only has removable singularities, and $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\,dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$ by integration by parts.

Comment: It doesn't work because the function you used does **not** yield the original *real* function...

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I am trying to find the principal value .@DonAntonia Can you please elaborate.How it does not yield the original function.

Comment: I am simply saying that $$\text{PV}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\,dx$$

Comment: Thanks @JackD'Aurizio.But can you please give me a clue how and why my method does not work.